# Android: Inserting data into SQLite database difficulties

Tags: android, sqlite

I have `List` of objects I want insert into database. I've created insert insert inside foreach loop, but it still ends with exception constraint failed. In my table I have created column `'_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL`. My insert method looks like

```
    public void insertData(List<Item> list) {
        dbAdapter = DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(getActivity());
        dbAdapter.openDataBase();
        for (Itemm item : list) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("item_id", item.getItemId());
            values.put("item_category", item.getItemCategory());
            values.put("order_number", item.getOrderNumber());
            dbAdapter.insertRecordsInDB("order_list", null, values);
          }
          dbAdapter.close();
}
```

Here's DBAdapter class:

```
public class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/<my_package>/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "mydatabase.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;

    private static DBAdapter myDBAdapter;

    /**
     * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
     * access to the application assets and resources.
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    private DBAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * getting Instance
     * 
     * @param context
     * @return DBAdapter
     */
    public static synchronized DBAdapter getDBAdapterInstance(Context context) {
        if (myDBAdapter == null) {
            myDBAdapter = new DBAdapter(context);
        }
        return myDBAdapter;
    }

    /**
     * Creates an empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
     * database.
     **/
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {
            // By calling following method
            // 1) an empty database will be created into
            // the default system path of your application
            // 2) than we overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
     * time you open the application.
     * 
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        //SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
        boolean checkdb = false;
        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            File dbfile = new File(myPath);
            //checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            checkdb = dbfile.exists();
        }
        catch(SQLiteException e){
            System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
        }

        return checkdb;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
     * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
     * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    /**
     * Open the database
     * 
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        if (!myDataBase.isReadOnly()) {
            myDataBase.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Close the database if exist
     */
    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    /**
     * Call on creating data base for example for creating tables at run time
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    /**
     * can used for drop tables then call onCreate(db) function to create tables
     * again - upgrade
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    // ----------------------- CRUD Functions ------------------------------

    /**
     * This function used to select the records from DB.
     * 
     * @param tableName
     * @param tableColumns
     * @param whereClase
     * @param whereArgs
     * @param groupBy
     * @param having
     * @param orderBy
     * @return A Cursor object, which is positioned before the first entry.
     */
    public Cursor selectRecordsFromDB(String tableName, String[] tableColumns,
            String whereClase, String whereArgs[], String groupBy,
            String having, String orderBy) {
        return myDataBase.query(tableName, tableColumns, whereClase, whereArgs,
                groupBy, having, orderBy);
    }

    /**
     * select records from db and return in list
     * 
     * @param tableName
     * @param tableColumns
     * @param whereClase
     * @param whereArgs
     * @param groupBy
     * @param having
     * @param orderBy
     * @return ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>
     */
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> selectRecordsFromDBList(
            String tableName, String[] tableColumns, String whereClase,
            String whereArgs[], String groupBy, String having, String orderBy) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> retList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.query(tableName, tableColumns, whereClase,
                whereArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                list = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    list.add(cursor.getString(i));
                }
                retList.add(list);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return retList;

    }

    /**
     * This function used to insert the Record in DB.
     * 
     * @param tableName
     * @param nullColumnHack
     * @param initialValues
     * @return the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred
     */
    public long insertRecordsInDB(String tableName, String nullColumnHack,
            ContentValues initialValues) {
        return myDataBase.insert(tableName, nullColumnHack, initialValues);
    }

    /**
     * This function used to update the Record in DB.
     * 
     * @param tableName
     * @param initialValues
     * @param whereClause
     * @param whereArgs
     * @return true / false on updating one or more records
     */
    public boolean updateRecordInDB(String tableName,
            ContentValues initialValues, String whereClause, String whereArgs[]) {
        return myDataBase.update(tableName, initialValues, whereClause,
                whereArgs) > 0;
    }

    /**
     * This function used to update the Record in DB.
     * 
     * @param tableName
     * @param initialValues
     * @param whereClause
     * @param whereArgs
     * @return 0 in case of failure otherwise return no of row(s) are updated
     */
    public int updateRecordsInDB(String tableName, ContentValues initialValues,
            String whereClause, String whereArgs[]) {
        return myDataBase.update(tableName, initialValues, whereClause,
                whereArgs);
    }

    /**
     * This function used to delete the Record in DB.
     * 
     * @param tableName
     * @param whereClause
     * @param whereArgs
     * @return 0 in case of failure otherwise return no of row(s) are deleted.
     */
    public int deleteRecordInDB(String tableName, String whereClause,
            String[] whereArgs) {
        return myDataBase.delete(tableName, whereClause, whereArgs);
    }

    // --------------------- Select Raw Query Functions ---------------------

    /**
     * apply raw Query
     * 
     * @param query
     * @param selectionArgs
     * @return Cursor
     */
    public Cursor selectRecordsFromDB(String query, String[] selectionArgs) {
        return myDataBase.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs);
    }

    /**
     * apply raw query and return result in list
     * 
     * @param query
     * @param selectionArgs
     * @return ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>
     */
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> selectRecordsFromDBList(String query,
            String[] selectionArgs) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> retList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                list = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    list.add(cursor.getString(i));
                }
                retList.add(list);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return retList;
    }

}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. How can I insert data from my list into DB? Every help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please post your logcat stack trace :)

Comment: I'm sorry but at the moment I can't because I don't have my PC now. But my logcat trace looks like this: ERROR/Database(446): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed. I've tried to find solution, but unsuccessfully. It looks like that I'm not attching to the contentvalues value for the primary key or some column value is NULL.

Comment: The only constraint on your table is the `primary key`, so you're probably trying to insert an item with a `Non-Unique-ID`.

Comment: `SQliteDatabase db=dbAdapter.openDataBase(); 
 db.insertRecordsInDB("order_list", null, values); 
 Change your 
 public SQliteDatabase openDatabase() throws SQlException
 {
   //add return myDataBase;
  }`

 OR

`Change db.insert into -->
 return myDataBase.insertWithOnConflict(tableName, nullColumnHack, initialValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);`

Comment: @VikalpPatel do you mean like this

public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        if (!myDataBase.isReadOnly()) {
            myDataBase.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
        }
        return myDatabase;
    }

Comment: In the text you stated the primary key column is named `_id`, in the code its `item_id`. I would expect that your stacktrace shows an exception indicating that the column `item_id` does not exist or that the primary key is missing.

Comment: @Stefan I have 4 columns _id PK, item_id, item_category, order_number. So in contentvalues I don't put _id. Is it necessary if _id is AUTOINCREMENT PK?

Comment: Can I put id as values.("_id", null);

Comment: No, you do not need to provide for the insert operation, only for updates (or deletes). You do not need to provide a null value.